# python sorting of dictionary based on keys

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list as follows:

```
list1 = [['abc',{2:1,10:8,7:4,3:4,5:6}],['xyz',{3:8,5:7,2:4,1:9}],.......]]
```

I want to write the list in a o/p file in the below mentioned format where all the dictionary items are sorted in increasing order based on the key values.

```
'abc' 2:1 3:4 5:6 7:4 10:8

'xyz' 1:9 2:4 3:8 5:7
```

I have written the code as follows:

```
for k, v in list1:
    outputfile.write(k + ' ' + ' '.join('{}:{}'.format(key, val) for key, val in v.items()) + '\n')
```

But I am not able to get the desired result. Please help me with a solution for it.

Comment: What is `finallist`?

Comment: it is same as  list1,name of my list

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
for k, v in list1:
    print k + ' ' + ' '.join(
        '{}:{}'.format(key, val)
        for key, val in sorted(v.items(), key=lambda x: x[0])
    ) + '\n'
```

or use [`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) instead lambda:

```
from operator import itemgetter

for k, v in list1:
    print k + ' ' + ' '.join(
        '{}:{}'.format(key, val)
        for key, val in sorted(v.items(), key=itemgetter(0))
    ) + '\n'
```

Comment: The lambda is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` function to sort keys

**Demo**:

```
list1 = [['abc',{2:1,10:8,7:4,3:4,5:6}],['xyz',{3:8,5:7,2:4,1:9}],]

for i in list1:
    tmp = ""
    for j in sorted(i[1].keys()):
        tmp += " %s:%s"%(j, i[1][j])
    print "'%s'   %s\n"%(i[0], tmp)
```